# Can you run python code with Hadoop Streaming API in Azure HDInsight?

Tags: python, azure, hadoop, mapreduce, azure-hdinsight

I see that you can run C# code (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-develop-deploy-streaming-jobs/.) And presumably any other compiled language since that example uses .exe files.

Can you do the same thing using python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not had much luck running Python mapreduce on HDInsight. While Python is there on the Windows cluster, I have received pipe errors trying to use it for streaming mapreduce.

However, HDInsight on Linux clusters was announced as a preview today, and Python works for streaming mapreduce there. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-streaming-python/

Comment: That looks very promising! Thanks!